# Changing size of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, transform

I'm trying to modify the size of an UIView by changing the frame's size, not by scaling. At the same time I want to rotate or translate the view, but as the documentation says the frame property must be ignored after applying transformations to the view.

Given these conditions, is there a way to resize the UIView without scaling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also change the view's `bounds` to modify its size.